# Is there a way that I can send data from Sign-Up Form to another HTML Page?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, authentication, account

I am creating a static website using plain front-end technologies(HTML/CSS/JavaScript). I want to register an account through a form and pass the user's information (excluding the passwords for now) to display it on another HTML page. Not only do I want to pass the information to the profile page, but also I want to save and store the user(s) information. All of my JavaScript codes are external. I used id and name attributes to link the desired location for the data.

Below are snippets of my code below.

signup.html

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="container">

        <div id="firstheading">
            <h1>Login</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="form-login">
            <form action="profile.html" method="POST" class="form" id="form" onsubmit="return validate();">

                <div class="col">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" for="proEmail" id="proEmail1" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Professional Email">
                    <div class="error_msg" id="pemail_err_msg">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" for="password" id="passwordLogin" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Password">
                    <div class="error_msg" id="pw_err_msg">

                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Log in</button>
                </div>
                <p class="form__text">
                    <a href="#" class="form__link">Forgot your password?</a>
                </p>
                <p class="form__text">
                    <a id="linkCreateAccount"
                        href="file:///C:/Users/sykes/Documents/Personal%20Projects/Consulting%20Website/Signup.html"
                        class="linkLogin">Create An Account</a>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End of Container-->

</div>
```

signupdata.js (linked in signup.html)

```
<script>
function signupForm() {

    var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname");
    var lastname = document.getElementById("lastname");
    var proEmail = document.getElementById("proEmail");
    var schoolEmail = document.getElementById("schoolEmail");
    var password = document.getElementById("password");
    var password2 = document.getElementById("password2");

    if (proEmail == 1 && schoolEmail == 1) {
        firstname.style.border = "1px solid #ff8471";
        error_message("fn_err_msg", "An account with these email(s) already existed.");
    }
    else if (password != password2) {
        firstname.style.border = "1px solid #ff8471";
        error_message("fn_err_msg", "Password Must Match.");

    }
    else {
        if (typeof (localStorage) != "undefined" && proEmail != 1 && schoolEmail != 1) {
            localStorage.name = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
            localStorage.name = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
            localStorage.name = document.getElementById("proEmail").value;
            localStorage.name = document.getElementById("schoolEmail").value;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
</script>
```

setSignUpData.js (linked in profile.html)

```
<script>

function setData() {
    if (typeof (localStorage) != "undefined") {
        document.getElementById("firstname").innerHTML = localStorage.name;
        document.getElementById("lastname").innerHTML = localStorage.name;
        document.getElementById("proEmail").innerHTML = localStorage.name;
        document.getElementById("schoolEmail").innerHTML = localStorage.name;

    }
}
</script>
```

profile.html

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="container">

        <div id="firstheading">
            <h1>Welcome to your Student STEM Website Profile</h1>
        </div>

        <label for="firstname" id="firstname">First Name: </label><br>
        <label for="lastname" id="lastname">Last Name: </label><br>
        <label for="biography">Biography</label><br>

        <label for="college">Community College or University: </label><br>
        <label for="major">Major</label><br>

        <label for="proEmail" id="proEmail">Professional Email: </label><br>
        <label for="schoolEmail" id="schoolEmail">School Email: </label><br>

        <label for="linkedin">LinkedIn Profile</label><br>
        <label for="github">Github Profile</label><br>
        <label for="resumecv">Resume or CV</label><br>

        <label for="phonenumber">Phone Number</label><br>
    </div>
    <!--End of Container-->

</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, "*it is still unsuccessful*" is not a particularly clear problem statement. Please edit your post to explain why *specifically* this attempt does not meet your requirements (including expected vs. actual behaviors, as well as the full text of all relevant error messages), as well as to better conform to our [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines.

Comment: Can you also share some insight into why you've overwritten the contents of a single variable (`localStorage.name`) over 4 consecutive lines in your script? In this scenario, `setData()` will always set the value of `localStorage.name` to the `innerHTML` of your `schoolEmail` element (provided that one of the previous lines doesn't throw an unhandled exception). Any reason you haven't elected to store each of these input field values in distinct `localStorage` keys?

Comment: @esqew I used name four times, and I thought that it is referring to the attribute instead of the id's or actual value of the respected name. Here is the link that I researched this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67475357/is-there-a-way-that-i-can-send-data-from-sign-up-form-to-another-html-page

Comment: Sorry for my continued confusion, but the name attribute of *what* exactly? Please also check your link, as it refers to this same question.

Comment: @esqew this is really my first time using localStorage.name as well. I am open to your insight as well.

Comment: @esqew maybe should I make the actual name variable value of the firstname, lastname, proEmail, and schoolEmail instead of name in all four places? For example, I have name="firstname" in the signup.html form. Should it be be something such as ```localStorage.firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;```?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues in your script:

#### 1. `localStorage.name` isn't a real property.

It's not clear where you originally saw this convention, but `window.localStorage` is an instance of a [`Storage`-type object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage), which (as the linked MDN page states) does not have a `name` attribute by default.

#### 2. You're overwriting the value you've placed in `localStorage.name`.

For argument's sake, let's say that you could store data in `localStorage.name` and have it persist across pages as it seems is your understanding. When you execute a line like so:

```
localStorage.name = 'hello!';
```

... what you're telling the JavaScript interpreter is "interpreter, please store the string data `hello!` in the variable `localStorage.name`", which it will do happily. The issue here is that you've told the interpreter to do this over and over again:

```
localStorage.name = 'hello!';
localStorage.name = 'goodbye!';
localStorage.name = 'sayonara!';
```

Again, the interpreter will happily process each of these in order. However, the end result of these three lines is that `localStorage.name` is now set to the string `sayonara!`, and anything else you've tried to stuff in there is now lost/overwritten.

It's important to remember that the interpreter (and, more generally, computers as a whole) will do *exactly* what you tell it to; it cannot determine that your intention is to store these variables separately for later use unless you explicitly do so.

#### 3. The `Storage` API requires the use of its getter/setter methods.

Unfortunately, you can't directly manipulate properties on a `Storage` object in this way and persist this data as intended across pages on your domain (the associated [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) makes this clear; you should review it). Instead, setting a property requires the use of the [`setItem()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem):

```
localStorage.setItem('name', 'John Smith');
```

The above line sets the value of the local storage key `name` to the string `John Smith`. If we wanted to go back and retrieve the value we stored there later, we'd reference its key as the sole parameter for [the `getItem()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem):

```
localStorage.getItem('name'); // returns 'John Smith'
```

In your scenario, you'd set the `innerHTML` or `innerText` property of your target element to the value you've stored on this key.

#### 4. You don't ever trigger your `setData()` function.

As such, the data you store in `localStorage` won't ever be painted into the DOM. Add a button to your interface that triggers this function, or execute it as a callback to an event listener of your choice.

Comment: When I originally attempted to trigger my ```setData()``` function, it automatically redirected me to profile.html as soon as I clock on the form.

Comment: How is that possible? `setData()` isn't relevant in the scope of your registration form (at least not the way you've laid it out here). Can you be a bit more specific? It seems like what's happening is your `form` element is `POST`ing to your `profile.html` page, when you're trying to handle the form's submission through your JavaScript. However, you haven't appropriately prevented this action from happening. You should be configuring your form and JavaScript handler to be trapping the event per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted)

Comment: For example, <body onsubmit="setData()">

Comment: I would recommend you revisit your HTML and JavaScript fundamentals, and to critically evaluate the sources from which you are getting this information. `body` tags do not respond to `submit` events, and there is no such `onsubmit` tag as part of [`body`'s specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body#attributes). Can you provide a source on which you're basing your implicit assumption otherwise?

Comment: the same link that I gave you earlier.

Comment: There also is no method called `setData()` that would be included on your registration page; as you've indicated, the file in which this function is defined (`setSignUpData.js`) is only "linked" to `profile.html`.

Comment: The link you gave me earlier points back to the page we're conversing on currently. Do you have an authoritative source to a specification that indicates `body` should respond to `submit` events?